# Obtaining dimensions for Stewart Platform for arm, base and top plate

Tags: robotics, servo, kinematics

I am in a need to calculate the Stewart platform dimensions for an application where the Stewart platform top plate can be, consisting of a width of 19Inches maximum, and length 19Inches. Also, the height should not exceed, 25Inches. The Stewart platform should be able to withstand 100kg. The maximum tilt angle expected to achieve is 20Degrees. This Stewart platform operates using 6 servo motors at each leg.

The following website was referred to obtain the calculation so far.
https://memememememememe.me/post/stewart-platform-math/

Comment: please show us what you did so far? maybe show us a [mcve] of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe the following paper is of help to accomplish your goal: https://www.xarg.org/paper/inverse-kinematics-of-a-stewart-platform/ But creating a Stewart Platform that can withstand 100kg with a rapid movement is hard. Try searching for diy motion platforms. A lot of people already tried to build custom flight simulators.